# How to get the value of an element from a multidimensional JSON string array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

This is the array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array

   (
        [product_details] => {"5f93f983524def3dca464469d2cf9f3e":{"id":"110","qty":1,"option":"{\"color\":{\"title\":\"Color\",\"value\":null}}","price":1400,"name":"Foot Massage","tax":null,"image":"http:\/\/acme.dev\/uploads\/product_image\/product_110_1_thumb.jpg","coupon":"9","book_date_":"2017-04-19","book_date_name_":"wed","start_timeslot_":"09:00:00","end_timeslot_":"10:00:00","has_already_rescheduled":0,"discount_":"0","rowid":"5f93f983524def3dca464469d2cf9f3e","subtotal":1400}}
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_details] => {"2723d092b63885e0d7c260cc007e8b9d":{"id":"109","qty":1,"option":"{\"color\":{\"title\":\"Color\",\"value\":null}}","price":700,"name":"Body Massage","tax":0,"image":"http:\/\/acme.dev\/uploads\/product_image\/product_109_1_thumb.jpg","coupon":"","book_date_":"2017-04-18","book_date_name_":"tue","start_timeslot_":"09:00:00","end_timeslot_":"10:00:00","has_already_rescheduled":0,"discount_":"0","rowid":"2723d092b63885e0d7c260cc007e8b9d","subtotal":700}}
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [product_details] => {"a3c65c2974270fd093ee8a9bf8ae7d0b":{"id":"108","qty":1,"option":"{\"color\":{\"title\":\"Color\",\"value\":null}}","price":3000,"name":"Alo","tax":0,"image":"http:\/\/acme.dev\/uploads\/product_image\/default.jpg","coupon":"","book_date_":"2017-04-21","book_date_name_":"fri","start_timeslot_":"10:00:00","end_timeslot_":"12:00:00","has_already_rescheduled":0,"discount_":"0","rowid":"a3c65c2974270fd093ee8a9bf8ae7d0b","subtotal":3000}}
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [product_details] => {"a3c65c2974270fd093ee8a9bf8ae7d0b":{"id":"108","qty":1,"option":"{\"color\":{\"title\":\"Color\",\"value\":null}}","price":3000,"name":"Alo","tax":0,"image":"http:\/\/acme.dev\/uploads\/product_image\/default.jpg","coupon":"","book_date_":"2017-04-12","book_date_name_":"wed","start_timeslot_":"08:00:00","end_timeslot_":"10:00:00","has_already_rescheduled":0,"discount_":"0","rowid":"a3c65c2974270fd093ee8a9bf8ae7d0b","subtotal":3000}}
    )

)
```

What I need is to create a new simple array containing the values from all the "id" elements.

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: Those aren't serialized arrays.

Comment: I freaked out a little for a minute there.

Comment: @Daniel please check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43951364/6521116)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this simple `foreach` will be helpful for you.

**Solution 1:** [**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/793573)

```
$result=array();
foreach($array as $value)
{
    $array=  json_decode($value["product_details"],true);
    $result[]=$array[key($array)]["id"];
}
print_r($result);
```

Here we are using `array_column` to extract `product_details` then we are using to `array_map` to iterate over `$personalDetails` which contain all the `JSON`'s then we are using to `key` function which will return first key of the array, and through that key we are accessing, its `id`.

**Solution 2:** [**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/793570)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$array = Array
    (
    0 => Array
        (
        "product_details" => '{"5f93f983524def3dca464469d2cf9f3e":{"id":"110","qty":1,"option":"{\"color\":{\"title\":\"Color\",\"value\":null}}","price":1400,"name":"Foot Massage","tax":null,"image":"http:\/\/acme.dev\/uploads\/product_image\/product_110_1_thumb.jpg","coupon":"9","book_date_":"2017-04-19","book_date_name_":"wed","start_timeslot_":"09:00:00","end_timeslot_":"10:00:00","has_already_rescheduled":0,"discount_":"0","rowid":"5f93f983524def3dca464469d2cf9f3e","subtotal":1400}}'
    ),
    1 => Array
        (
        "product_details" => '{"2723d092b63885e0d7c260cc007e8b9d":{"id":"109","qty":1,"option":"{\"color\":{\"title\":\"Color\",\"value\":null}}","price":700,"name":"Body Massage","tax":0,"image":"http:\/\/acme.dev\/uploads\/product_image\/product_109_1_thumb.jpg","coupon":"","book_date_":"2017-04-18","book_date_name_":"tue","start_timeslot_":"09:00:00","end_timeslot_":"10:00:00","has_already_rescheduled":0,"discount_":"0","rowid":"2723d092b63885e0d7c260cc007e8b9d","subtotal":700}}'
    ),
    2 => Array
        (
        "product_details" => '{"a3c65c2974270fd093ee8a9bf8ae7d0b":{"id":"108","qty":1,"option":"{\"color\":{\"title\":\"Color\",\"value\":null}}","price":3000,"name":"Alo","tax":0,"image":"http:\/\/acme.dev\/uploads\/product_image\/default.jpg","coupon":"","book_date_":"2017-04-21","book_date_name_":"fri","start_timeslot_":"10:00:00","end_timeslot_":"12:00:00","has_already_rescheduled":0,"discount_":"0","rowid":"a3c65c2974270fd093ee8a9bf8ae7d0b","subtotal":3000}}'
    ),
    3 => Array
        (
        "product_details" => '{"a3c65c2974270fd093ee8a9bf8ae7d0b":{"id":"108","qty":1,"option":"{\"color\":{\"title\":\"Color\",\"value\":null}}","price":3000,"name":"Alo","tax":0,"image":"http:\/\/acme.dev\/uploads\/product_image\/default.jpg","coupon":"","book_date_":"2017-04-12","book_date_name_":"wed","start_timeslot_":"08:00:00","end_timeslot_":"10:00:00","has_already_rescheduled":0,"discount_":"0","rowid":"a3c65c2974270fd093ee8a9bf8ae7d0b","subtotal":3000}}'
    )
);
$personalDetails=  array_column($array, "product_details");

$result=array_map(function($value){
    $array=json_decode($value,true);
    return $array[key($array)]["id"];
}, $personalDetails);
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 110
    [1] => 109
    [2] => 108
    [3] => 108
)
```

Comment: Is array_map faster than foreach? Or it really doesn't matters.

Comment: `foreach` is faster

Comment: you don't need to use `array_column` here, `json_decode($value['product_details'],true);` will do the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

you may use array_map & array_value to achieve this,

here is a quick example, and you need to modify it to be fit with your needs :

```
$ar = [
    0 => ['product_details' => '{"5f93f983524def3dca464469d2cf9f3e":{"id": 3}}'],
    1 => ['product_details' => '{"2723d092b63885e0d7c260cc007e8b9d":{"id": 8}}'],
    2 => ['product_details' => '{"a3c65c2974270fd093ee8a9bf8ae7d0b":{"id": 5}}'],
    3 => ['product_details' => '{"a3c65c2974270fd093ee8a9bf8ae7d0b":{"id": 1}}'],
];

$ar = array_map(function ($value) {
    return array_values(json_decode($value['product_details'], true))[0]['id'];
}, $ar);

print_r($ar);
```

live demo : https://3v4l.org/koXee

Comment: Hi bro, it's my fault. I didn't notice inner is a json string. I edit my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43951364/6521116), check it.

Answer (score 1):

use  `array_column   and json_decode`

```
    $new_one = array_column($array,'product_details');
    $new_array=[];
    foreach($new_one as $key=>$row)
    {    
     foreach(json_decode($row,true) as $key1=>$row1)
     {
         $new_array[]=$row1['id'];
     }

    }

    print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, **[live demo](https://eval.in/793580)**

```
print_r(array_column(array_map(function($v){return current(json_decode($v));},array_column($array, 'product_details')), 'id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You "product_details" seems to be a JSON string. Loop through your array, decode the JSON and store the "id" in a new array.

Comment: Agree with Tom's comment above. So here's an explanation to a possible solution. Implementing the code shouldn't be that hard.